# Java if two buttons have the same icons increase score and if not display "wrong match"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Creating a really basic Memory game using Java Swing.  I created my GUI with a list of blank buttons where I set the icon property to none.
My code for some of the buttons is:

```
 private void tbtnCard3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    tbtnCard3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Card3Logo.png")));
    if(tbtnCard5.isSelected()){
        score++;
        lblScore.setText(""+score);
    }
}                                         

private void tbtnCard4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     tbtnCard4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Card7EWaste.png")));
    if(tbtnCard7.isSelected()){
        score++;
        lblScore.setText(""+score);
    }
}                                         

private void tbtnCard5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     tbtnCard5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Card3Logo.png")));
    if(tbtnCard3.isSelected()){
        score++;
        lblScore.setText(""+score);
    }
}
```

I have about 20 toggle buttons and for example the code above works and the scores go up by 1 when a match is found.  So for tbtnCard3, if tbtnCard5 is selected the score goes up by 1.  Now my question is how would I make it so that if tbtnCard3 is selected but tbtnCard 5 is not selected, display "Wrong Match".  Since im using if Selected I'm not too sure how to display "wrong match" when the case is false. It doesn't make sense to say else ifSelected as no parameters can be put either....

Comment: This [Match Game](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/match-game) explanation and code might be helpful.

Comment: Made some edits above^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the OPs suggestion is not a good approach. You do not want the listener of one button to be "aware" of some other component unnecessarily. Suppose you have an 8-by-8 grid with toggle buttons. You don't want each toggle button listener to be aware of the other 63 toggle buttons.

I believe there is a much simpler (and cleaner) approach. What you want is for the toggle button listener to register and deregister the toggle when the state of the button changes. Let say, you add the toggle button to or remove from a list (most likely a custom class) where you can trigger some logic when the list size reaches two. Then, depending on the outcome of the comparison, it will count a match (and disable these two toggle buttons in the current state), or will display some message like "Try again" and then toggle the buttons to hide the image.

In pseudocode, this will look something like this:

```
public class ToggleListener implements ItemListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ItemEvent event) {
        JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) event.getSource();
        if (event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            // TODO Add the button to your list..
        } else {
            // remove button
        }
    }
}
```

In your Swing application, you can create a single instance of the above listener and add it to every single toggle button. And, as you can see, this listener is only responsible to register and unregister the component associated with the triggered event.

The "List Listener" on the other hand, is responsible to trigger the comparison logic when the size of the list reaches two. So, if you click on the same toggle button over and over again, the only thing the button listener will do is add or remove the button from the list depending on the button's current state. However, once a second button is toggled to reveal its image, the list listener will trigger the comparison logic. I am not 100% sure, but I think you could use JavaFX `ObservableList` interface or one of its implementing classes to do this. If the `ListChangeListener.Change` class is not suitable to figure out the size of the list to trigger the logic, you will have to implement this on your own. Regardless, in pseudocode, you need to do something like this:

```
public void onListChange(Event event) {
    if (list.size() == 2 && btn1.getIconName().equals(btn2.getIconName())) {
        displayMatchMessage();
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        list.clear(); // you should remove matched items from list manually
    } else {
        displayMismatchMessage();
        btn1.setSelected(false);  // flip the card
        btn2.setSelected(false);  // flip the card
        // list.clear(); // you should not need this because the setSelected should trigger the Item Listener which should remove item from list.             
    }
}
```

Doing something like this is a much cleaner implementation where the button listener have a single job to do and the "list listener" has another job to do. Neither one encroaches on the other's job.